# Does a superconductor spinning in a magnetic field radiate?

Tags: superconductivity, synchrotron-radiation

According to the cyclotron radiation formula:

$$ \frac{dE}{dt} = - \frac{\sigma_t B^2 V^2}{c \mu_0 }$$

charges will radiate even when moving perpendicular to the magnetic field (which presumably wouldn't be expected to do work on them, since they are perpendicular, but somehow this is still the case).

The question though, is what would happen if a superconductor is spin on a magnetic field. Since the superconductor repels the magnetic field, it is nonzero only on the skin, so presumably if this radiation expression applies to the skin currents, one should see a superconductor slowly lose rotational energy via radiation

Is this the case?

Comment: Charges don't radiate because of the magnetic field, but because they are being accelerated (by the magnetic field). Whether a rotating magnet loses energy depends on the shape of its magnetic field. If there is no dipole or higher moment that rotates, the answer should be "no". Having said that, the energy loss for realistic angular frequencies would be minute because the magnetic antenna (in the 0.001-1m range) would be so much smaller than the wavelength (in the 1-10,000km range) of the electromagnetic wave.